# Excel to XML when XSD includes recursive structures as list of lists

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, xlsx, xls

I'm trying to export **Excel forms** to **xml** documents by **converting** an **xsd schema** into an **xlsx Excel** form document (cf : [Overview of XML in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-XML-in-Excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80)). As mentioned in Microsoft Office Support, **recursive structures** are not supported (cf: [Map XML elements to cells in an XML Map](http://support.office.com/en-us/article/Map-XML-elements-to-cells-in-an-XML-Map-ddb23edf-f5c5-4fbf-b736-b3bf977a0c53)).

---

My question is twofold:

1. Is there any solution to the problem of a one deep recurcive definition while not modifying the XSD Input shema?
2. If there is no solution to the previous question, how could I transform a one deep recusive definition of an element into a non recursive one knowing that I'm willing to map the transformed xsd schema into a user-friendly xlsx form.

---

Bellow a one deep recurcive definition :

```
<xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="a"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>...</xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="att1" ... />
                <xsd:attribute name="att2" ... /> 
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
         </xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:attribute name="Att1" ... />
         <xsd:attribute name="Att2" ... /> 
     </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
```

Comment: What does this mean: *Excel forms*? The userforms modules? Those are code objects and not data. Please explain (or better show) the current input and desired output.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I meant by Excel forms, simple xlsx tables mapped from an xsd schema. Each column of the table correspond to an attribute of an xsd element.

Comment: In fact my inputs are XML files, but those file data are generated by ordinary users. So I opted for an Excel table as a rapid way to generate my input data. (No need to develop any code to get my input xml files)